# N-th roots equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am facing the following equation and I do not have any idea about how to solve it.
$\dfrac{(n^c-1)^a}{n^{ac}}$ = $\dfrac{1}{2}$. I am free to choose $c$ (any constant). $a$ on the other hand can be any polynomial. I am not sure of what tags I should put here. Any editing will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to express $n$ in terms of $a,c$. Take $a$th roots to get
$$ 1 - n^{-c} = \frac{n^c-1}{n^c} = 2^{-1/a}. $$
Therefore $n^{-c} = 1-2^{-1/a}$, and so $n = (1-2^{-1/a})^{-1/c}$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $1-n^{-c}=2^{-1/a}$?

Comment: That's right. Thanks for the correction.